# Why is $\nabla \times B$ perpendicular to $B$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, vector-fields

I'm considering a magnetic field inside a load capacitor where

$$\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\textbf{B} =\mu_{0} \varepsilon_{0} \frac{\partial\textbf{E}}{\partial t}\\
\textbf{j}_{c}=0.$$

Why is $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\times\textbf{B}$ is perpendicular to $\textbf{B}$?

Comment: Do you mean the cross product here?

Comment: In English schools the cross product/curl is often taught with the wedge symbol.

Comment: Yes cross product

Comment: Don't the Wedge and cross product coincide in three dimensions?

Comment: In general $\nabla \times {\bf B}$ isn't perpendicular to ${\bf B}$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The condition that the magnetic field and its curl be orthogonal is satisfied, generally, for plane-wave situations where the curl is given simply by $\nabla\times\mathbf B = i\mathbf k\times \mathbf B$, as well as a number of similarly 'nice' geometries, but it is **not** a general property of electromagnetic fields.

In the specific case you refer to ─ the magnetic field induced by the displacement current inside a charging capacitor ─ is a bit tricky because what you have is a differential equation for $\mathbf B$,
$$
\nabla\times\mathbf{B} =\mu_{0} \varepsilon_{0} \frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t},
\tag1
$$
where the source $\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$ is assumed to be known and homogeneous over space (possibly with some time dependence), and this differential equation does *not* have unique solutions. This means that we *must* put in additional constraints to mold it to our needs: we normally choose the solution
$$
\mathbf B = (Cy,-Cx,0)
$$
for $C$ a constant and with $\frac{\partial\mathbf{E}}{\partial t}$ along $z$, because it's the most useful one (but note that it has an unphysical dependence on the origin!). However, the magnetic field
$$
\mathbf B = (Cy,-Cx,B_0)
$$
is also a solution of $(1)$, and it no longer satisfies $\mathbf B \cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf B)=0$, so the property is not inherent to the statement of Ampère's law ─ it comes from the external conditions we impose on the problem. In other words, in that problem $\mathbf B \cdot(\nabla\times\mathbf B)=0$ because we want it to.